# How to find size of vector that is a member of a class through a pointer that is also in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a class that contains a vector and the class adds a pointer to itself in another vector. In a separate function i have a for loop that goes through the vector containing the class pointers and print the size of the vector in the class, but I get no output.

here's the source file with the function and definition of the class constructor:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

#include "InputManager.h"

//Vector including class pointers
std::vector<Button*> buttons;

//Constructor for class
Button::Button (std::initializer_list<SDL_Keycode> list) {
    buttons.push_back(this);

    for ( auto nkey : list )
    {
        this->keys.push_back(nkey);
    }
}


void inputScan (SDL_Keycode inKey, bool nState) {

for (auto bAddrs : buttons)
    {
        std::cout << (bAddrs->keys).size();
    }
}
```

and here's the header with the class declaration:

```
#pragma once

class Button
{
public:

    std::vector<SDL_Keycode> keys;
    bool state = 0;
    //Member vector who's size i'm trying to output
    Button (std::initializer_list<SDL_Keycode> list);
};

void inputScan (SDL_Keycode, bool);
```

edit:
After reading the comments I found out the the `buttons` array is actualy empty.
It should be filled out by the constructor.

Here's an example of a class instance being made in my main file that includes the header:

```
Button BUp({SDLK_w, SDLK_UP});
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks okay. But it could just be my inexperience. What compiler error are you getting exactly? Please edit your question and put it in verbatim.
`

Comment: Code looks fine, the reason for your problem is something else. If you get no output then the most likely reason is that the `buttons` vector is empty. So ask yourself why that might be.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. when the function is called I get no out put.

Comment: @cooljacwty Then like I said, that's because the `buttons` vector is empty.

Comment: Too much code missing, in particular code that instantiates the `Button` objects and adds their addresses to vector `buttons`.   Without that, nobody can help - the best they can does is make guesses about what code you haven't shown is doing or not doing.   Read up on providing a [mcve]

Comment: I did some more debugging, and turns out it is empty. Im gonna figure out why now

Comment: So apparently when I cout the size of ```buttons``` in the constructor it shows that it is increasing, but when I do the same thing in the ```inputScan``` function i get 0.

Comment: Are you sure that the code that calls the constructor happens *before* the call to `inputScan`?

Comment: Yes, the constructor is called right after the include statements.

Comment: @cooljacwty There could be many reasons why this is happening. It's really impossible to say without seeing a complete program.

Comment: @cooljacwty You misunderstood Karl's question. He wasn't asking about the location of the constructor in the code (after the include statements like you said), he was asking about the *timing* of your calls to the constructor, do they happen before or after the call to `inputScan`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the method I used is correct. I fixed the issue by moving the function into the header file.